# Powerbi Report Not working, Access Token related

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbuilder, powerbi-embedded

I got a problem that prevents me from moving forward. I want to embed Power BI report into my own web application. I am following the "embed for your customers" scenario with the master user option.

I struggle to embed the report in my web app. Where the report should be displayed, power BI API returns a "this content isn't available". I am wondering if it has something to do with the access token.

How to generate an access token for each user connecting to my web app to see the report? I am using react to build my web app.

Comment: Be sure you have created a service principal for your application and grant **Member** or **Admin** permission to the workspace in which you have published your embedded report.
Link: [Add the service principal to your workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#step-4---add-the-service-principal-to-your-workspace)

Comment: "Master User" is an alternative to "Service Principal" for embedding.

Comment: Indeed you're right, David. I used the Master User approach but it still does not work. My associate posted a more detailed message about this issue :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75226412/how-to-embed-power-bi-report-in-react-app-access-token-master-user-etc?fbclid=IwAR24bZar-QHurWNTWx7AnUIIrnBMaBb2-vF6zUQpkrYXrqmv1zq5c367f7I. Could you please help us on this ?