# How to Embed Power BI Report in React app ? Access Token, Master User etc

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am creating a react web application to display power bi reports to my customers.

The flow is the following :

- My customers connect on my website, go to the login page, get authenticated with firebase and then  redirected to the dashboard page where they can see the power bi report embedded.

I am following a "embed for customers scenario" with a master user approach.

If I understood well, the authentication flow is like that :
_ When a user authenticate with firebase, he goes to the dashboard page
_ to render the power bi dashboard, I first need to authenticate against Azure AD (with clientSecret, clientID and TenantID) and receive an access token for the user.

- Then I use that azure access token to call power bi api call and load and render the power bi report on my web app.

Here is my code for dashboard.jsx, where I try to embed the power BI report :

```
import React from 'react'
import { PowerBIEmbed } from 'powerbi-client-react';
import { models } from 'powerbi-client';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


const obtainAccessToken = async () => {
  try {
      const tokenUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${import.meta.env.VITE_AZURE_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token`;

      const headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      };

      const body = new URLSearchParams();
      body.append('client_id', import.meta.env.VITE_AZURE_CLIENT_ID);
      body.append('client_secret', import.meta.env.VITE_AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET);
      body.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
      body.append('resource', 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api');

      const response = await axios.post(tokenUrl, body, { headers });
      console.log('access token = ' + response.data.access_token);
      return response.data.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
  }
};

function Dashboard() {
  
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    obtainAccessToken().then((token) => {
      setAccessToken(token);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
      <PowerBIEmbed
        embedConfig = {{
          type: 'report',   // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual and qna
          id: 'eff45871-db5c-4bd6-a953-c492f6045044',
          embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=eff45871-db5c-4bd6-a953-c492f6045044&groupId=b1554fa1-bd00-4640-850f-efc22a60b64c&w=2&config=eyJjbHVzdGVyVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9XQUJJLUZSQU5DRS1DRU5UUkFMLUEtUFJJTUFSWS1yZWRpcmVjdC5hbmFseXNpcy53aW5kb3dzLm5ldCIsImVtYmVkRmVhdHVyZXMiOnsibW9kZXJuRW1iZWQiOnRydWUsInVzYWdlTWV0cmljc1ZOZXh0Ijp0cnVlfX0%3d',
          accessToken: accessToken,
          tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
          settings: {
            panes: {
              filters: {
                expanded: false,
                visible: false
              }
            },
            background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
          }
        }}

        eventHandlers = { 
          new Map([
            ['loaded', function () {console.log('Report loaded');}],
            ['rendered', function () {console.log('Report rendered');}],
            ['error', function (event) {console.log(event.detail);}]
          ])
        }
          
        cssClassName = { "Embed-container" }

        getEmbeddedComponent = { (embeddedReport) => {
          window.report = embeddedReport;
        }}
      />

        )
  }

export default Dashboard
```

The result I get with this code, a forever loading power BI logo and the following errors in the chrome dev tool console :

[dashboard page waiting for power bi to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR2y9.png)

[chromeDevTool console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5q0l.png)

It seems like I cant get the access token from Azure AD. Maybe there is another problem I cant see. Has anyone an idea on how to solve the issue ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: If I get you, the user will login with the `Masteruser`  account credentials and then he will get authenticated and he should able to see the report right ?

Comment: Actually I now try with the Service Principal approach (recommended by Microsoft). The user login with his own personal credentials (my own authentication with firebase). The authenticated user get redirected to the dashboard page. To load the dashboard, I must execute code behind the scenes to get Azure Ad access token, then use it to get an embed token to interact with power bi api and then embed the correct report. I am struggling with all the authentication steps with Microsoft (Azure and power BI)

Comment: LMK, if this is the requirement you are looking or anything different ?

Answer (score 3):

Using [React Developer Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/React-TS) we can Embed for organization. But in your case, embed for customers, In MSAL-React, ClientCredential Auth flow is designed for Confidential Client applications. msal-react is an auth library which supports only SPA type of apps which are public client applications, hence there is no support for ClientCredential flow in the library.

So, workaround is to get the Embed Token from Azure Function.

1. Create a [HTTP Trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal) in azure portal and implement C# code to get the token using the client_credentials.
2. Get the function URL and in React App fetch the URL to get the embedUrl, Access Token for Embedding Report.

Feel free to Reach out if you face any problems with creating the function and code to get the token in azure portal.

You can Refer to [React Demo](https://github.com/KotanaSai21/powerbi-embedded-React-demo) GitHub Repository.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

Maybe to late, but i will show how I managed to solve it using @azure/react and @azure/msal-browser library.

First of all you need to register Power BI for your organization. More you can find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/register-app?tabs=customers

After that if you have client_id for your power bi application from azure portal you need to create **new instance** of msal instance which might looks like this:

```
const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: registered_power_bi_client_id,
        authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_app_id,
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
};

export const instance = new PublicClientApplication(config);

const loginRequest: PopupRequest = {
    scopes: [power_bi_scope], // might look like this https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/Report.Read.All
    account: currently_logged_in_user,
    redirectUri: redirect_uri, // page when 
};

export const getPowerBiToken = async () => {
    let token;

    try {
        await instance.initialize();
        const res = await instance.acquireTokenSilent(loginRequest);
        token = res?.accessToken
    } catch {
        const res = await instance.acquireTokenPopup(loginRequest);
        token = res?.accessToken;
    }

    return token;
};
```

Then `getPowerBiToken` func you can utilize inside youre component logic.

If you login for the first time to the app the popup should appear asking for login. After successfull login you should get proper access token.

After that token should be acquired silently using `acquireTokenSilent` method.

Comment: Hi, I cannot find the package `@azure/react` you mentioned, and also cannot find any function named "PublicClientApplication" in @azure/msal-browser or @azure/msal-react. Could you please clarify it? Thanks in advance!